# Source File Not Found in Angular CLI project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Hi I have this folders in my project
[image: Folders]
But When I run I get this error
[image: Error]

Any idea please?

regards

Comment: what does your `empledo.ts` file contains?

Comment: this might be due to compilation errors in empleado.ts file. Share your empleado.ts file code

Comment: Can you stop and restart your "ng serve". It may be because it does not know the new file added.

Answer (score 74):

Rerunning `ng serve` should help fix the issue. You must have added `empleado.ts` while the local server was still running, hence Angular would not have seen the file.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to @Hisham Afzal Ahamed for the solution (stopping and re-starting the Angular compiler).

- Stop the compiler: `CTRL-C, CTRL-C` (or `CTRL-C` then `Y`)
- Restart: `ng serve` (or whatever else you're using e.g. a custom `npm` script)

Basically the Angular CLI sometimes doesn’t ‘see’ files that have been pulled in (e.g. when doing a merge while your compiler is running). Very useful to know. As a *general* time saver, If you’re pulling files into your solution or doing something similar, or you get an Angular compiler error that makes no sense, or you've made significant changes somehow, it’s always worth stopping then restarting the compiler to do a fresh build - it can save so many headaches!

Answer (score 5):

When application is running state and at that if you add a file with some export class then it through this type error

**ERROR in Source file not found: '/C/abc/xyz/pqr/apps/src/app/comm/ab.ts'.**

*Solution*

**restart application again then it works.**

> By using `npm start` command

Answer (score 3):

After execute npm start again all works fine
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this error with the verifications of Angular 4 onwards.
You can solve this error like this.

1. For the execution <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C)</kbd>
2. Run or initialize the server (`ng serve` or `npm start`);

Answer (score 3):

**Simplest Solution:**

I also had the same issue,

The file was present in the directory but it was showing the above error.

Everything was proper but the error was not going.

then I closed the tab and again went to the directory through command prompt and again started the server:

```
ng serve --open
```

The error went !!!

Comment: This was the solution for me too. But it repeats to come again severally.

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you try to create a file using your IDE viz VS code etc. while your code is still compiling. You can stop the server using ctrl+c and then start then start it again using ng serve command to resolve the issue. Make sure that you saved all the files before running ng serve command .

Answer (score 1):

From my experience:

Just press ctrl with c (ctrl + c) to stop the compiler. Then re-run the command: ng serve

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `empleado.ts` file into assets folder and then fetch the file from there.

As, angular recommends to put all your resources in the assets folder including images/fonts/json etc and access from there.

PS: assuming this file contains your static content like dummy data etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `empleado.ts` is your class model for empleado, so you need to import in in your app.module

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that "source file not found".

This same error I was also getting. In my case by mistake I created a .ts file while ng server was running. The file was not needed so deleted it, from that point I stared getting the error.

I restore the file again without any code and the error is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

i also get this error

```
export class Product {

constructor(
  public productname: string,
  public qty: string,
  public price:string
) {  }
```

}
this my product.ts 
file

solution:

the error is that i have written productname as product-name or product_name 
this both things are not allowed 
so i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If your file is modal file, give extension to the file name. Do not keep it just with extension .ts ,for example empledo.modal.ts.

If your file is constants file, give extension to the file name as empledo.constants.ts.

Or you can keep file in asset folder if its dummy data and if it's not required.