# Angular throws "ERROR in Source file not found" after introducing new models. How to solve it?

Tags: angular, typescript

I had a working project including a service that was stored in a file called *demo.service.ts*. In the same file I had two classes that was my model, like so.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class DemoService { ... }
export class Donkey { ... }
export class Monkey { ... }
```

Each file that used that service and model imported all three classes like this.

```
import { DemoService, Donkey, Monkey } from "../demo.service";
```

Then I decided to refactor to keep the model classes in a separate file called *demo.model.ts*. Of course, I had to alter the import statement as follows.

```
import { DemoService, Donkey, Monkey } from "../demo.service";
import { Donkey, Monkey } from "../demo.model";
```

The errors reported in the console got less and less as I've kept updating. However, now that all the imports are altered, I still get the error message below.

> ERROR in Source file not found: '/C/.../src/app/demo/demo.model.ts'.

I have no idea what is trying to get to the file nor why it can't find it. Googling produces a lot of errors from sites unrelated to Angular or [blogs like this](https://nehalist.io/working-with-models-in-angular/) that seem to work after doing the equivalent of my attempt.

I tried to remove or change the imports in each of the files using them and got immediately more error messages. Hence, I concluded that those are pointing to the correct locations.

What more can I dig up to trouble-shoot this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Source File Not Found in Angular CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233046/source-file-not-found-in-angular-cli-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue and finally fixed it with omitting the component class (`DemoComponent` in your case) from `declarations` array in `app.module.ts` .

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this error while building with Ionic. So I exited live reload (`Ctrl + C` on command prompt) and recompiled the app (`ionic serve` or in your case, `ng serve`).