# angular : changing a file sends error and should restart 'npm'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

When I change a file in my angular application it sends error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/@theme/components/auth/index.js Module build
>   failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Dev\Ng\ngx-admin\src\app\@theme\components\auth\index.js' i ｢wdm｣:
>   Failed to compile.

And when I terminate the ng serve and re run, it is correct.

I dont want to re run it again.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you attempting to edit the transpiled .js file from a non-existant TypeScript source file?

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI cannot actually see files that you add when the server is running.

So it is better to give a fresh build by command.

```
CTRL C

ng serve -o
```

A similar question was asked here it will help to solve your doubt:

[Source File Not Found in Angular CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233046/source-file-not-found-in-angular-cli-project)

Comment: i dont what to terminate the npm and rerun it i want it do it automatically